# Time complexity of Math.abs in Java?

Tags: java, math, time, complexity-theory

For an assignment I'm doing, I need to make sure I have an algorithm running in O(n) time, and I'm using the Math.abs() function inside some loops, so I'm wondering if `Math.abs()` runs in O(1) time?

I would think that it would, but I can't find an answer to this anywhere. Just want to make sure I'm not accidentally making an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm without knowing it.

Comment: Conceptually `Math.abs()` is just flipping a sign bit from negative to positive, if it has been set, and this operation should be similar for any input.

Comment: Why are people negating the response or the question? Have we become so intolerant of questions or responses?

Comment: I did not vote, but I can say that asking a question without demonstrating effort attempts to turn SO into google. The source code for Java is available. In a class that purports to have students prove running time, I would expect the student to examine the source code of method calls, provide justification that the method calls (such as Math.abs()) is O(1) (or whatever it is), and that the method itself is O(n) (or whatever).

Comment: I think he has a genuine doubt and a valid question on what is the time complexity of running an O(1) function. Put it another way, I have seen some silly questions without any research are top scorers in this site. So, please let's not do moral policing always.

Comment: It's not obviously O(1), but remember that basic operations on `int` like `+`, `-`, `*` are all O(1) because they can be done with hardware.

Comment: It is obviously O(1). The evaluation doesn't depend on the input value in any conceivable way, and the input length is 1.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Being able to do it in hardware doesn't make it O(1). Consider `fmod()` for example, or floating-point division.

Comment: @EJP - The requirement here is also saying it is about loop of n times which is an input. Time Complexity of a loop is considered as O(n) if the loop variables is incremented / decremented by a constant amount.

Comment: @Suparna No it isn't about loops. The question is "I'm wondering if Math.abs() runs in O(1) time"

Comment: @EJP It's not inconceivable that negation could require a linear search of the bits to find, say, the first set bit. It could quite conceivably be O(log n) or something like that. It's only obviously O(1) if you know how it really works.

Comment: @PaulBoddington the `n` in your `O(log n)` would be the number of bits, i.e. 64 or less. So it would still be constant time with respect to the `n` in the op's question which is the number of iterations...

Comment: The question doesn't state what `n` is.

Comment: @KevinO what even made you think I gave no effort to figure out the answer to this on my own in the first place? I tried many things, including trying to find the Java source code for the abs() method, but I was still unclear, so I came here and asked a question. How about you only contribute helpful responses instead of assuming I'm a complete idiot and feeling like you need to point it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Math.abs** implementation:

```
public static int abs(int a) {
    return (a < 0) ? -a : a;
}
```

This will be O(1) time complexity, since the operation itself is constant time and the input is fixed. Regardless of the input, the operation will always take the save time.

**Loop:** O(n): Time Complexity of a loop is considered as O(n) if the loop variables is incremented / decremented by a constant amount. For example following functions have O(n) time complexity.

```
   // Here c is a positive integer constant   
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += c) {  
        // some O(1) expressions
   }

   for (int i = n; i > 0; i -= c) {
        // some O(1) expressions
   }
```

Comment: Next time you can try just editing your original answer rather than posting a new one.

Comment: I would usually do that, but for no reasons I got beaten up with -3 votes when I just posted the code before even finishing my edit. And moreover I wanted to earn Peer pressure badge. :)

Comment: *"but for no reasons I got beaten up with -3 votes"* Your "answer" was just the `Math.abs` code and "now help yourself" and you don't know why some users downvoted that? Really?

Comment: See this is where this site gets confusing - sometimes people like yourself say do not solve assignments of kids. And when you don't and just give them enough to get started, you start moral policing. I don't want to repeat myself, but this is no way to treat a person who has barely set steps on this site.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a straightforward answer unlike anybody who commented on my actual question.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what data type you performing the `abs` function:

1. **IEEE754 floating point**

   `abs` means just clearing of `MSB` bit which holds the mantissa sign bit. This is unconditional bit operation on single well placed bit so it is `O(1)`. Here C++ example (sorry not a JAVA programmer)

   ```
   float x;         // 32bit variable to perform abs on
   int *p=(int*)&x; // this just makes p pointer pointing to x
   p[0]&=0x7FFFFFFF;   // clear highest bit by AND
   ```
2. **non 2'os complement signed integer types**

   These have separate sign bit just like previous bullet so all the stuff from **#1** applies for these too.

   ```
   int x;         // 32bit variable to perform abs on
   x&=0x7FFFFFFF; // clear highest bit by AND
   ```
3. **2'os complement signed integer types**

   `abs` for these means negate the sign if **MSB** is set. That means you need to negate all bits an increment.

   ```
   int x;         // 32bit variable to perform abs on
   if (int(x&0x80000000)!=0) // negative means MSB is set
    {
    x^=0xFFFFFFFF; // negate all bits
    x++;           // increment
    }
   ```

   This can be done also brunch less. Anyway for basic data types is this still `O(1)`. But if you start using `bigint` or `bigdecimal` then both negation of all bits and incrementation will become `O(n)` where `n` is the number of "digits" used to form the number. By the "Digit" I mean what base is used to internally store the number. usually it is `2^32` or `2^64` word or highest power of `10` that can be fit inside such number. That is why is usually better not to use 2'os complement for big numbers ... (it complicates thing not just `abs` operation).

**Conclusion**

On basic data types you can safely assume `abs` is `O(1)` and also most HW architectures support this operation as an atomic instruction.